# not able to evaluate nested formula in excel using apache poi java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hi I am trying to Evaluate a cell value with Nested formula using
apache POI 4.1.0. When I am trying with Normal formula it works fine.
Conisder the below code:

```
FileInputStream inputExcelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(INPUT_FILE_NAME)); 
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputExcelFile);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Total");             
Row row = sheet.createRow(0); Cell cell = row.createCell(0);     
//setting formula in the cell    
cell.setCellFormula("IF('Data Set'!B2=0,CONCATENATE(IF('Data Set'!J2="","UMS",'Data Set'!J2),"_",IF('Data Set'!K2<>"",'Data Set'!K2&"_",""),'Data Set'!H2),"");

Cell cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);
```

Now, if do `cell.setCellFormula("CONCATENATE(F4,"/",G4)")` or any direct formal this code works fine but when using nested formula like "IF(....,CONCATENATE(IF...))" it throws the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: Error evaluating cell Total!A1
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.addExceptionInfo(WorkbookEvaluator.java:344)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:285)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:216)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:145)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:85)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:34)
    at com.example.com.CollibraAutomationScript.evaluateFormula(CollibraAutomationScript.java:255)
    at com.example.com.CollibraAutomationScript.main(CollibraAutomationScript.java:164)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: Error evaluating cell 'Data Set'!B2
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.addExceptionInfo(WorkbookEvaluator.java:344)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:285)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:792)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:39)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:217)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.RelationalOperationEval.evaluate(RelationalOperationEval.java:66)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:541)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:275)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: Error evaluating cell 'Data Set'!A2
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.addExceptionInfo(WorkbookEvaluator.java:344)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:285)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:792)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyRefEval.getInnerValueEval(LazyRefEval.java:39)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromRef(OperandResolver.java:217)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Countif.evaluateCriteriaArg(Countif.java:498)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Countif.createCriteriaPredicate(Countif.java:470)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Countif.evaluate(Countif.java:442)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:541)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:275)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: _xlfn.CONCAT
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.UserDefinedFunction.evaluate(UserDefinedFunction.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:541)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:275)
    ... 31 more
```

So apache poi does not allow to exceute nested formula? because when i put this same formula in excel sheet its evaluating properly.

Comment: Whats the formula in `'Data Set'!A2`?

Comment: `Error evaluating cell 'Data Set'!A2` means you need to check what's going on in A2; at least, that's where I would start.

Comment: Not sure if that will be useful in your case but in my opinion it is the best option to delegate recalculation to Excel itself (which will happen whenever someone opens the file). For that to happen you just have to call `workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);`. It saves quite a lot of hassle if you just have to manipulate the file from Java and nothing else (no printing and such).

Comment: `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: _xlfn.CONCAT` is your primary issue. Most probably used in the `Data Set` sheet. Though might also be an old version you are using

Comment: @XtremeBaumer i do not understand why is it evaluating 'Data Set'!A2, because if u see  my  formula its not even there! and when i try to put this formula directly into excel it works but through code its giving error! and by old version you mean old version of excel ?

Comment: `cell.setCellFormula("IF('Data Set'!B2=0,CONCATENATE(IF('Data Set'!J2="","UMS",'Data Set'!J2),"_",IF('Data Set'!K2<>"",'Data Set'!K2&"_",""),'Data Set'!H2),"");` you put that formula into excel according to your code. I mean old version of apache poi. The older that version the less functions are supported